# How to apply a mask to an input image in Keras

Tags: image-processing, keras

From Keras documentation this is one example to use `IamgeDataGenerator` to get images from disk and feed it to fit method:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
```

For each input image I want to apply a mask on that image and then use it for the fit method. The masks are not already on disk and must be calculated for each input image. For example, I binarize the input image to select certain regions of the image to make the mask, then by applying the mask I want to have that specific region of the image as input. How can I apply masks to images as they are being read from disk by `ImageDataGenerator`?

Comment: are they calculated or are they random? where are the masks coming from?

Comment: I calculate the mask from the image itself by applying some morphological operations such as otsu thresholding and convex hull.